# Is it possible to make my fixed menu responsive?

Tags: html, css, menu, responsive-design, fixed

I have been attempting to make my menu responsive. [www.treytrumble.com](http://www.treytrumble.com)
It seems that because it is fixed, it will not scale properly when viewed on a device smaller than a laptop. What can I do to make the menu appear like this one when the screen is scaled to smaller than 1,150px wide? http://www.adtile.me

HTML

```
<div class="contactcontainer">
<div class="contactmenu">Trey Trumble<br /><br/>804-513-7704 <br/><br/>
<a href="mailto:trey@treytrumble.com" class="font5">trey@treytrumble.com</a><br/><br/><a      
href="images/Trey Trumble Resume.pdf" class="font5">Resume</a>
</div><!-- end .contactmenu -->

</div><!-- end .contactcontainer -->
<div class="container">

<div class="sidebar1">
<table width="120" height="104" border="0">
<tr>
<th scope="col"></th>
</tr>
</table>
<ul class="nav">
  <li><img src="images/logo.jpg" width="180"/></li>
  <li><a id="webbutton" class="nav">WEB DESIGN</a></li>
  <li><a id="printbutton" class="nav">PRINT DESIGN</a></li>
  <li><a span class="contactbutton">CONTACT &amp; RESUME</span></a></li></ul>
</div><!-- end .sidebar1 -->
```

CSS

```
.content ul, .content ol { 
padding: 0 15px 15px 40px;
}


ul.nav {
list-style: none;
border-top: 1px solid #666;
margin-bottom: 15px; 
position:fixed;
}
ul.nav li {
border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
letter-spacing: 2px;
font-family: "Helvetica", Arial, sans-serif;
cursor: pointer;
}
ul.nav a, ul.nav a:visited {
padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
display: block;
width: 160px;
text-decoration: none;
background: #fff;
inline-box-align:initial;
color:#F60;

}
ul.nav a:hover, ul.nav a:active, ul.nav a:focus {
background:#F60;
color: #FFF;
font-family: "Helvetica", Arial, sans-serif;
letter-spacing: 2px;
font-size: 9px;
}
```

Comment: Why just the menu? The site is not responsive, has no meta viewport tag, is using old jQuery, not using html5, and so forth. If you view this on a mobile device it will look fine and the user can pinch zoom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite simple to accomplish, but it's quite a bit hard to explain. You have to use media queries to accomplish this, maybe even JavaScript.

### Media Queries

Chris Coyier has a very interesting article in **CSS-TRICKS** that explains various concepts of responsive menus here: http://css-tricks.com/responsive-menu-concepts/

As for the main question, you can definitely make that menu **responsive**, though, I wouldn't suggest you put the exact same layout you have for desktop for mobile, because that would be a problem since the screen is too small, I would suggest making it go all the way to the top like a normal menu, being responsive, you can also fix it to the top and adding a `padding-top` to the remaining elements so that they don't go below the menu.

If you decide that the menu should be always on top, make sure you add a `z-index` property to the `nav` or `div` element so that no other goes across it too.

### FlexBox

There is another approach you can take as well, but depending on what support you're giving to certain browsers I would suggest or not using Flexbox. If you display your navigation as `display: flex` and you tweak it CSS wise, you can achieve beautiful combinations, but again, remember this is a slightly new CSS3 property, and mainly Internet Explorer has just recently began supporting it.

More about Flexbox can be found here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

### Responsive Design

If you're new to responsive/adaptive design, then sir you have a lot of work to do, but, luckily for you, there are today tons of free and/or paid resources that will give you a pretty good idea of what to do.

I found this article on Team Tree House very useful: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design

You can go on from there and start looking for other resources, some of them mentioned on this answer:

- Media Queries
- Flexbox

### Other Tips

If you want to make your menu responsive, you also need to make your site responsive, make sure you have all these:

- Responsive viewport tag
- HTML5 doctype
- A plan (grid system, media queries, flexbox, etc)
- Fallbacks for unsupported content

Answer (score 0):

Of course yes,

use media queries to choose the resolution you want it to snap to.

Define your classes within the query and apply it around the menu.